# Create uitableview in sub view of segment type tabs

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, ios7

i am developing a app that have 3 tabs like segment tabs when user tap a tab it will load a uitable within the view so i have 3 tabs i which i want to load 3 different uitableviews. let me most my code so far.

ViewDidLoad Code:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    DKScrollingTabController *leftTabController = [[DKScrollingTabController alloc] init];

    leftTabController.delegate = self;
    [self addChildViewController:leftTabController];
    [leftTabController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:leftTabController.view];
    leftTabController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 170, 320, 60);

    leftTabController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:0.6 blue:0.7 alpha:1.0];/// Baby Pink Color
    leftTabController.buttonPadding = 53.3;
    leftTabController.underlineIndicator = YES;
    leftTabController.underlineIndicatorColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    leftTabController.buttonsScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    leftTabController.selectedBackgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    leftTabController.selectedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    leftTabController.unselectedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    leftTabController.unselectedBackgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    leftTabController.selection = @[@"PLACE\n0", @"PLACE\n0", @"PLACE\n0" ];
    [leftTabController setButtonName:@"Ingredients\n07\nCount" atIndex:0];
    [leftTabController setButtonName:@"Nutrition\n334\nCalories" atIndex:1];
    [leftTabController setButtonName:@"Directions\n30\nMinutes" atIndex:2];

    [leftTabController.buttons enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        UIButton *button = obj;
        button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
        button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

        NSString *buttonName = button.titleLabel.text;
        NSString *text =  [buttonName substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, [buttonName rangeOfString: @"\n"].location)];
        NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:buttonName];
        NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10] };
        NSRange range = [buttonName rangeOfString:text];
        [attributedString addAttributes:attributes range:range];

        button.titleLabel.text = @"";
        [button setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
#pragma mark - TabControllerDelegate

- (void)DKScrollingTabController:(DKScrollingTabController *)controller selection:(NSUInteger)selection {
    if (selection == 0) {
        NSLog(@"index 1");
    }if (selection == 1) {
        NSLog(@"index 2");
    }if (selection == 2) {
        NSLog(@"index 3");
    }
}
```

So far it is nsloging correctly but i dont know how to load uitable within these tabs. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

ObjectiveC has a build in tab bar. You can easily load this.

Regarding the loading of different data for each tab in the table. You have
different options:

- Load each time the correct data in the table.
- Have all data in the table (eg in different sections and hide/display them)
- Have 3 different tables (on different uiViews).
- Have different UIViewControllers
- Probably also other options.

I would go for the different tables on different UIViews options.